# Use rspec with capybara-webkit or selenium to measure page load times

Tags: ruby, rspec, performance-testing

I'm hoping to find a way to write rspec scripts (or something else) that can be used to measure page load times. So similar to how firebug can tell when a page has fully loaded, is there a similar way to do that in rspec?
Or even any other ruby gem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use benchmark in your views:

```
<% benchmark("Showing projects partial") do %>
<%= yield %>
<% end %>
```

If you do this in your application layout you'll have a log with page loads:

```
Showing projects partial (0.0ms)
```

Comment: Sorry, I was asking about Rspec because I'm using it with other web dev stuff, not for a Rails site.

Comment: Jty.tan can you provide more details and code? What template language are you using? If none, since benchmark is part of ruby you can use it.

Comment: Let's assume just any website. If I wanted to measure page load times of this specific stack overflow page, as an example, is there a way to do that programatically through ruby and rspec? or even just through Ruby? I'm starting to wonder if possibly the way forwards is to find a way to generate a HAR....